# How to Auto-Capitalize a text input in phonegap for Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

Is there a (non hacking) way to set `autocapitalize="on"` (like iOS) in phonegap for Android?

If not, is there any way to "auto press" shift after the user focuses on a form field such as `<input ... type="text">`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a textarea width height: 22px (or more).

```
<textarea style="height: 22px" ...></textarea>
```

Discovered by accident, using ICS with cordova 1.9.0

Answer (score 3):

via jQuery:

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('keypress', function() { 
    var $this = $(this), value = $this.val(); 
    if (value.length === 1) { 
      $this.val( value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() );
    }  
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Just use css

```
input[type=text] {
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

Comment: I want just the first letter to be uppercase http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization